# In probability indentical items and distinct items are treated same?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If we have 5 red indentical balls and 3 green indentical balls,
The probability of green ball is 
3C1/8C1.
But no of distinct outcomes is only 2 red or green but we write 8C1.

Comment: Because each *ball* is equally likely to be drawn; it is in this situation, where each outcome is equally likely, that we count outcomes to compute probabilities. If you follow your concern, you mistakenly conclude that red and green are equally likely to be drawn.

Comment: "I win" and "I loose" are distinct outcomes.  Therefore I have an equal probability of winning the Lottery as losing.  No?  Awe... So, measuring probability by counting distinct outcomes only works when each outcome has an equal "weight".

Answer (score 1):

We can *only* use the count for outcomes in events to measure their probability, *when* each *individual* outcome has an *identical* probability weight.  They must be equally probable.

Now the balls are not *distinguished* except by colour, but they really are *individual* balls, and there are *different counts* for individual balls are of each colour.

So the events of "drawing a colour" are not equally weighted, while the events of drawing "specific balls" are. We can use the later as our *equally probable outcomes*.

So the probability for obtaining one from three green balls when drawing any one from all eight balls is: $\left.{^3\mathrm C_1}\middle/{^8\mathrm C_1}\right.$ … which is $3/8$.